# Facebook Pixel doesn't recognize external_id parameter

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, event-tracking, facebook-pixel

I used official Facebook documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/conversions-api/parameters/customer-information-parameters) to add external id parameter, but it is only visible in Facebook Events Manager (Test events).

[image]

In Events deduplication it is shown as 0% sent (Conversion API however, has no problem with this parameter detection).

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this package, it will help to simplify tracking using a Facebook Pixel. It also supports multiple pixel Ids. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-multi-pixel

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

OK it seems that external id need to be added as an advanced matching parameter, in the third parameter object of the `fbq('init', XXX, {external_id : "HERE"})` method.

But it won't appear in the Test Event tool as mentionned in the [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/conversions-api/parameters/external-id)